# Error "wrong ELF class" using ctypes

Tags: python, gcc, 32bit-64bit, ctypes

after changing from a 32 to 64Bit Ubuntu installation my `python+ctypes+c99` code is broken. I read so far, that the error `./libfoo.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` means, that my `libfoo.so`[1] is a 32Bit library and that python wants a 64Bit version. How do I tell `gcc/ctypes` to generate the library as 32Bit?

Thanks for any feedback!

**Error message:**

```
 File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    autofoo=cdll.LoadLibrary("./libfoo.so")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libfoo.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

[1] I compile `libfoo.so` with `gcc -c  -std=c99 -lm -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -pedantic -fopenmp -ofoo.o foo.c`

Comment: Can't you just use a 64-bit library?

Comment: Hi lunaryorn. I wrote the library 'libfoo.so' myself, so I assume, I have to set a flag or something to tell gcc to create a 64Bit version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the object file as 64 bit and position independent, then link the object file to the shared library with 64 bit options. Something like:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -m64 -std=c99 -lm -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -pedantic -fopenmp -o foo.o foo.c
gcc -m64 -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

That should get you a 64 bit library on any gnu toolchain I have used. If you are still getting errors, something might be broken in your toolchain or Python.

Comment: The second line did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Passing `-m64` to gcc will tell it to build 64-bit code if possible.

Comment: Hi IVA, thanks for the idea! I tried that, but it did not change the error. :/